# Best alternatives to replace a keyboard for those seeking a cheaper option than the Apple Magic Keyboard

Tags: keyboards

I’d like recommendations for an alternative to the Apple Magic keyboard which is:

- Cheaper (preferably under £50/$60)
- Has a membrane keyboard
- Does not have an extended layout (with a pad of numbers in the rightmost section of the keyboard)
- Uses the QWERTY layout
- For personal use
- Not too noisy (but this is lower priority)
- Wired or wireless are both OK

I can touch-type at 70 WPM if that is of any use. I’m not particularly interested in gaming keyboards; I just want something that does the job.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: @K7AAY Thanks for responding. I don't mind whether it's wired or wireless.

Answer (score 1):

The [Logitech Wireless Touch Keyboard K400 Plus](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-touch-keyboard-k400-plus) has [good reviews](https://www.macworld.com/article/2990826/logitech-wireless-touch-keyboard-k400-plus-review-stylish-couch-keyboard.html) and costs 28 quid at [Big Wide River Trading Company](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Logitech-K400-Plus-keyboards-Universal/dp/B014EUQOGK) or [$38 stateside at CDW](https://www.cdw.com/product/Logitech-Wireless-Touch-Keyboard-K400-Plus-keyboard-with-touchpad-bla/3819004).

Comment: Please also see https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I was searching on a review site, and I think the logitech Kxxx keyboards are what you are searching for.  The one I liked (from the pictures) was the K380. It's currently for sale in Belgium for around 50 euros (+-45 US dollars), but I don't know how expensive it is where you live.